# Spanner - delete one row or all rows from a table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I would like to delete one row or all rows from a spanner table. The primary key of the table is an int64. I do not want to drop the table and recreate it.  I am using the google supplied Java tutorial as a guideline (I am not a Java programmer - been a MS SQL Server developer since the product first came out).  Here's what I have as my code.  No rows are deleted and there is not an error thrown.

```
static void perfmonTestDelete(DatabaseClient dbClient) {
    LocalDateTime datetimeStart = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime datetimeEnd;

    Mutation.delete("productPerfmon",KeySet.all());

    datetimeEnd = LocalDateTime.now();
    long diffInSeconds = java.time.Duration.between(datetimeStart, datetimeEnd).getSeconds();
        System.out.println("DurationInSeconds:" + diffInSeconds);

}
```

Here's the code to populate 10 rows in the table that I want to delete from:

```
static void perfmonTest(DatabaseClient dbClient) {
    LocalDateTime datetimeStart = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime datetimeEnd;
    List<Mutation> mutations = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mutations.add(Mutation.newInsertBuilder("productPerfmon")
              .set("product_id")
              .to(i)
              .set("product_code")
              .to("test")
              .set("product_code_v")
              .to("test_v")
              .build());
    }
    dbClient.write(mutations);

    datetimeEnd = LocalDateTime.now();
    long diffInSeconds = java.time.Duration.between(datetimeStart, datetimeEnd).getSeconds();
        System.out.println("DurationInSeconds:" + diffInSeconds);

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete one or multiple rows you need to use a [singleKey](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/latest/apidocs/com/google/cloud/spanner/KeySet.html) or [keyRange](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/latest/apidocs/com/google/cloud/spanner/KeyRange.html) selector:

```
SpannerOptions options = SpannerOptions.newBuilder().build();
Spanner spanner = options.getService();
DatabaseClient dbClient = spanner.getDatabaseClient(DatabaseId.of(
        options.getProjectId(), "InstanceId", "databaseName"));

List<Mutation> mutations = new ArrayList<>();
// Single row by key
mutations.add(Mutation.delete("tableName", 
    KeySet.singleKey(Key.newBuilder().append("Key").build())));

// Multiple rows by range
mutations.add(Mutation.delete("tableName",
    KeySet.range(
        KeyRange.newBuilder()
            .setStart(Key.newBuilder().append("StartKeyIncl").build())
            .setEnd(Key.newBuilder().append("EndKeyNotIncl").build())
            .build())));
dbClient.write(mutations);
```

To delete all rows in your table you  can do:

```
List<Mutation> mutations = new ArrayList<>();
mutations.add(Mutation.delete("tableName", KeySet.all()));
dbClient.write(mutations);
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that Google Spanner is compliant with  ANSI SQL-2011. But I did not find any examples of DELETE, UPDATE, and INSERT in Cloud Spanner.

My understanding of SQL-2011, is that it definitely includes support for DELETE, INSERT and UPDATE.

In that case, adding rows or deleting them will become a single SQL statement, and the Java Client connecting using JDBC.

Comment: The documentation of Google Cloud Spanner states that the JDBC driver (currently) does not support DML and DDL: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/partners/drivers. If you want support for DML and DDL through JDBC, you could use this driver: https://github.com/olavloite/spanner-jdbc (Note: I am the author of the driver, but not affiliated with Google in any way)